# Redirection to load a CSS file

Tags: htaccess, redirects, css

I have in a remote server with this `index.html` that I can *not* modify:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

But my *styles.css* file is not at the web root, that is `/styles.css` but at `/css/styles.css`, is possible through an *.htaccess* file load that file?

I have tried with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /css/
</IfModule>
```

but it *styles.css* is not loaded yet.

NOTE: of course this is a minimal example, I would like to find a rule to load more than a CSS, not just one.

Comment: It's weird to have rights to modify an *.htaccess* file without having rights to modify the `index.html` which is in the same place. Are you sure you can't modify the `index.html`?

Comment: @Zistoloen not by the moment..

Comment: `href="styles.css"` is obviously a _relative_ path, but I assume is loaded at the root of your site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the browser should cache permanent redirects, I think an *internal rewrite* would be preferable. This avoids the browser having to make an additional HTTP request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+\.css)$ /css/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just redirect `/styles.css` to `/css/styles.css`.  In the *.htaccess* in the web root:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /([a-z]+\.css)$ http://example.com/css/$1
```

(Replacing `example.com` with your real domain name.)

Comment: @StephenOstemiller thanks, but as I said in my question I have many .css files, how to avoid writting the full list of the .css files?

Comment: I updated the answer with a RedirectMatch directive that would redirect all the css files that are in the root directory to the css folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to the .htaccess rules, you could include a styles.css file in the root, and just put @import statements in there that load the actual css files. Something like this:

**/styles.css**

```
@import 'css/styles1.css';
@import 'css/styles2.css';
...
```

I know it is an extra request and definitely not best practice, but it should be cached, and is a flexible and easy solution.